# Null conditional and ToString together give unexpected results

Tags: c#, null-conditional-operator

I have 2 statements that use the null conditional (?) operator and perform ToString on the result. These 2 statement seem like they should have the same result, but they do not. The only different is one includes parenthesis and the other does not.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace ByPermutationConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeClass someClass = default(SomeClass);

            // Why do these evaluate differently?
            //
            // (someClass?.StatusCode).ToString() is equal to an empty string
            //
            // someClass?.StatusCode.ToString() is equal to null
            //
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I expect these 2 statements to evaluate identically.

```
(someClass?.StatusCode).ToString() == someClass?.StatusCode.ToString()
```

However, they do not:

`(someClass?.StatusCode).ToString()` is equal to `string.Empty`

and `someClass?.StatusCode.ToString()` is equal to `null`

Comment: You could get the same result with `(someClass?.StatusCode)?.ToString();` which than again as Daniel A. White answer says it `short circuits` to null.

Comment: Check this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`someClass?.StatusCode` evaluates to `Nullable<HttpStatusCode>`. `ToString` on an empty `Nullable` results in empty string.

`someClass?.StatusCode.ToString()` short circuits the whole expression to `null`.

By using the parens, you are effectively breaking up the whole expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is wrong (well that was obvious), but let me explain why..

```
someClass?.StatusCode.ToString()
.........^ here the evaluation is already concluded to null - someClass is null

(someClass?.StatusCode).ToString()
.......................^ null to string will result in an empty string
```

Look at the point(^) in the code where the evaluation takes place. Without parenthesis the evaluation will immediately stop (it will never be ToString-ed). With parenthesis the evaluation takes place and then the ToString will occur.

Comment: I think the reason they are confused is because they dont know WHY the evaluation stops early. Because they dont understand how the null conditional operator works.

Comment: Hence the explanation using the code sample provided.. It should make some sense I hope

Comment: Your code says what happens. It doesnt explain why or how you know what happens.

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to look at the IL because what you're saying above essentially seems to be (null).ToString evaluates to an empty string which it does not. The only way that makes sense is if the type inside the paranthesis is essentially a Nullable one like Daniel White  is saying above.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said this is the result of the type created on the fly being Nullable. I should have thought about that.

As has been stated, the statement without parenthesis simply stops evaluation basically because anything to the right of ?. (short circuits) becomes null if what precedes the ?. is null. I understood how the operator works in that respect.

The statement with the parenthesis forces the creation of an instance of a Nullable type hence the empty string resulting from the call to ToString. This didn't occur to me although it probably should have.

I used LINQPad to get the IL and verify all of that. I should have just done that in the first place. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I do appreciate your answers though. Thank you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass someClass1 = default(SomeClass);
        string result1 = someClass1?.SomeNumber.ToString();

        SomeClass someClass2 = default(SomeClass);
        string result2 = (someClass2?.SomeNumber).ToString();
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
}



IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldnull
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // someClass1
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // someClass1
IL_0004:  brtrue.s    IL_0009
IL_0006:  ldnull
IL_0007:  br.s        IL_0018
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     // someClass1
IL_000A:  call        UserQuery+SomeClass.get_SomeNumber
IL_000F:  stloc.s     04
IL_0011:  ldloca.s    04
IL_0013:  call        System.Int32.ToString
IL_0018:  stloc.1     // result1
IL_0019:  ldnull
IL_001A:  stloc.2     // someClass2
IL_001B:  ldloc.2     // someClass2
IL_001C:  brtrue.s    IL_002A
IL_001E:  ldloca.s    05
IL_0020:  initobj     System.Nullable<System.Int32>
IL_0026:  ldloc.s     05
IL_0028:  br.s        IL_0035
IL_002A:  ldloc.2     // someClass2
IL_002B:  call        UserQuery+SomeClass.get_SomeNumber
IL_0030:  newobj      System.Nullable<System.Int32>..ctor
IL_0035:  stloc.s     05
IL_0037:  ldloca.s    05
IL_0039:  constrained. System.Nullable<System.Int32>
IL_003F:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_0044:  stloc.3     // result2
IL_0045:  ret

SomeClass.get_SomeNumber:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+SomeClass.<SomeNumber>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret

SomeClass.set_SomeNumber:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldarg.1
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+SomeClass.<SomeNumber>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret
```